# How to retrieve a value from a list of keys/values separated by pipes?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like:

```
String s = "a=xxx|b = yyy|c= zzz"
```

I am trying to write a function that returns the value corresponding to a given key but it does not work as expected (it returns an empty string):

```
static String getValueFromKey(String s, String key) {
  return s.replaceAll(key + "\\s*=\\s*(.*?)(\\|)?.*", "$1");
}
```

Test:

```
static void test() {
  String s = "a=xxx|b = yyy|c= zzz";
  assertEquals(getValueFromKey(s, "a"), "xxx");
  assertEquals(getValueFromKey(s, "b"), "yyy");
  assertEquals(getValueFromKey(s, "c"), "zzz");
}
```

What regex do I need to pass the tests?

Comment: What's the reason for not going for the more straightforward option of splitting into a map?

Comment: @chrylis to save some screen real estate! ;-)

Comment: Yeah, but this is getting into Real Programmer territory. :-P

Comment: Consider using `Pattern.quote(key)` to escape potential regex metacharacters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `replaceAll` here seems like overkill, because this method will have to iterate over entire String. Instead you could use Matcher and its `find` method which will stop after matching searched regex (in out case `key=value` pair).

So maybe use something like:

```
static String getValueFromKey(String s, String key) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(
            "(?<=^|\\|)\\s*" + Pattern.quote(key) + "\\b\\s*=\\s*(?<value>[^|]*)")
            .matcher(s);
    if (m.find())
        return m.group("value");
    else
        return null;// or maybe return empty String "" but that may be misleading 
                    // for values which are really empty Strings
}
```

Comment: That's a good point - the strings are fairly short so it would not make a huge difference except that in your example I can save the compiled regex for later use which could be a gain.

Comment: @assylias Actually I am afraid that you will not gain much by saving compiled regex because it is based on passed `key`, unless you want to save some general `key=value` pair regex like `(?<key>[^|]+)\\s*=\\s*(?<value>[^|]+)` and than test each match by comparing founded `key` with passed `key`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have those string you can use a simple regex like this :

```
X\s*=\s*(\w*)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/qD5sS3/1)**

[image]

As **[Michelle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/866104/michelle)** pointed in his comment you if you have apple and pineapple as keys then you can use word boundaries to avoid having a trouble:

```
\bapple\b\s*=\s*(\w*)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/qD5sS3/2)**

[image]

Comment: What if the keys are "apple" and "pineapple"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex for **matching**:

```
\W*(\w+)\W*=\W*([^|]*)
```

#### [RegExDemo](http://regex101.com/r/eY3hK9/2)

**Code:**

```
static void test() {
      String s = "a=xxx|b = yyy|c= zzz";
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\W*(\\w+)\\W*=\\W*([^|]*)");
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

      while (matcher.find()) {
          System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " :: " + matcher.group(2));
      }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
a :: xxx
b :: yyy
c :: zzz
```

Comment: The regex should match the whole string but the first group should be the matching value only. For some reason I can't get from your answer to that point.

Comment: I updated regex little bit and also posted Java code with output to that effect.

Comment: Alright I mixed your answer with Fede's and that works: `return s.replaceAll("(.*)?\\b" + key + "\\b\\s*=\\s*(\\w*).*", "$2");`. Cool and thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to the question it seems that you only want to change the regex and keep the same code structure. So you have to make sure that your regex match the full pattern, otherwise the string will still contain other data. So even if there are better ways to accomplish this, the answer is:

```
s.replaceAll(".*?\\b" + key + "\\s*=\\s*(.*?)($|\\|.*)", "$1");
```

You can test it [here](http://regex101.com/r/gM6yR3/1).

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do without regexpressions:

```
static String getValueFromKey(String s, String key) {
  string[] pairs = s.split("|");
  for (String p : pairs) {
      string[] halves = p.split("=");
      if (halves[0].equals(key)) {
          return halves[1];
      }
  }

  return "";
}
```

This code words by splitting the `String` `s` on the '|' charachter, creating an array of `String`s of the form "key=value". It then splits each of these key-value pairs on the '=' character until it finds `key`, and returns the associated value.

Is there a specific reason why you need to use a regular expression rather than an approach such as this?